# Extract data from HTML string in Python with PyQt WebView

Tags: javascript, python, html, pyqt

So i'm using the Google Maps API to work out the straight-line distance between 2 points on the map.

```
gmaps="""
***generic google maps HTML api stuff first, then:***

overalldist=calcDistance(firstcoord, secondcoord);
alert(overalldist)

//calculates distance between two points in km's
function calcDistance(firstcoord, secondcoord) {
      return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(firstcoord, secondcoord) / 1000).toFixed(2);
"""
```

This is within the script section of my HTML code which is all placed within a simple string in Python.
The string is called by:

```
self.webView.setHtml(gmaps)
```

Where gmaps is the string name that contains the HTML and webView is the name of the HTML viewer in my PyQt GUI.

The outcome is a popup box outputting the correct distance.

My issue is that I cannot extract the variable 'overalldist' from the HTML. The alert pops up with the correct distance but I then cannot move this into my Python code.

Please advise.

Any further ideas?

It is the function calcDistance I am attempting to retrieve from the HTML code to use in my Python code.

BuMp
bUmP

Comment: What do you mean by extracting the variable? You mean you can manipulate that value.

Comment: So you want to access a javascript variable's value from python? I don't know if qwebview supports that, you might have better luck with something like PyExecJS.

Comment: You need to use [evaluateJavaScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript), which will return the value of the last executed statement.

Comment: hi @ekhumoro , that is the right idea, however it only appears to work with QwebFrame which seems to be different from QwebView? Perhaps you could elaborate? thanks

Comment: @HelpMeWithPythonPlease. `self.webView.page().mainFrame()`.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks for your response. I have used this and placed it within my Python code as follows: `distancecalc = self.webView.page().mainFrame()` and then 
            `traveldistance=distancecalc.evaluateJavaScript(gmaps)`
           and attempted to output the result with 
       `print("distance", traveldistance)`. this gives me an output of "distance None" which suggests i'm doing something wrong. Could you please tell me whether i've use the code correctly? And finally, where i've got `evaluateJavaScript(gmaps)`, gmaps contains the whole HTML or just the JS btwn the <script> tags?

Comment: @HelpMeWithPythonPlease. You need pass in a call of the js function *as a string*, like: `"calcDistance(%s, %s)" % (first, second)` (assuming `first` and `second` are float values).

Comment: @ekhumoro, I have edited my original post with the entire HTML/JS/Python coding I am using. I wasn't successful with your previous comment, so wondered if you could take another look now you have full context of the coding I'm using? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @HelpMeWithPythonPlease. The `calcDistance` function is buried inside function inside another function. How do expect other code to be able to call it?